# Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation

Tags: web-part

I Created a web part and add **Event Receiver** to handle ItemAdded event.

When run in visual studio , i get error

**Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of questions

1. Are you deploying via Visual Studio? or Installing using STSADM/Powershell?
2. Did you follow the guidelines for setting up your permissions to deploy from Visual Studio - Read here for those steps: 
   http://rsuharta.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/error-occurred-in-deployment-step-activate-features-attempted-to-perform-an-unauthorized-operation/

The "unauthorized operation" is a very generic error and doesn't always tell you where you dont have permissions.

The link shared above though should help.

Comment: Unfortunately the web page of the link is now down.